# How to set cron in siteground's gogeek plan

Tags: cron

I am trying to a setup cron job in siteground's gogeek plan

I have trying set command like

```
/home/username/filename  */5 * * * *
```

and before I have tried which they have suggested like

```
/home/username/bin/my-backup
```

but it is not working, can you guys help me what is the problem I have facing.

I hope you understand what my question is.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`siteground` changed its format and there is no proper tutorial so I discuss with chat support and they gave me final command with worked for me:

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/customer/www/abc.com/public_html/main_files/yourfilename.php`

make sure you change your `domain` and `filename`